# I need to implement a WSN simulator for group leader selection, using matlab

Tags: matlab, simulation

I am trying to implement a wireless sensor network simulator on matlab and I need your help.

This is exactly what I want to do:

1. Deploy nodes randomly in a 2D plane.
2. Model a group leader election algorithm using two conditions:

   a) **Energy**: generate random energy values associated with each of the sensors, the sensor node with the maximum energy has higher probability of being selected as leader.

   b) **Proximity**: the sensor node that is mostly surrounded by neighboring nodes has higher probability of being selected.

So, for a random node that has maximum energy and more neighbors can be selected as leader and plotted with the rest of the nodes in a different color.

I have been working on this, trying to develop my code all to no avail. I am not really good with matlab coding, I am still learning.

Please guys, I need any help I can get on this, my deadline is imminent.

Thanks,
Ike

Answer (score 2):

First of all building a wireless networks simulator using matlab is by far not the best choice to do. its better to use specialized simulators such as NS2 or Omnet++. however, I have developed once a simple m-file code to randomly deploy points in a square are and try to link between these points according to the distance between these points. the points are assumed to be sensor nodes.

try to modify on it to get what you need. please vote up if this answer was useful to you:

```
 W=0;X=0;Y=0;Z=0;
 nodedistance = zeros();
 maxx = 400; maxy=400; maxn = 50;
 q = zeros(maxn);
 e = rand(maxn,1)*100;
 nodeloc = rand(maxn, 2)* maxx;
 node(maxn) = struct('NodeNum',zeros(maxn),'nEnergy',zeros(maxn),'Loc',[zeros(maxn,1), zeros(maxn,2)]);
 rss(maxn,maxn) = struct('NodeNumber',zeros(maxn),'NodeDistance',zeros(maxn));
 for a = 1:100,

 m = 2;
 node = struct();
 rss = struct();
 nodedistance = zeros();
 maxx = 400; maxy=400; maxn = 50;
 q = zeros(maxn);
 e = rand(maxn,1)*100;
 nodeloc = rand(maxn, 2)* maxx;
     for  i = 1: maxn,
          node(i)=struct('NodeNum',i,'nEnergy',e(i),'Loc',[nodeloc(i, 1), nodeloc(i, 2)]);
     end
     for i = 1:maxn,
     for j = 1:maxn,
      rss(i,j) = struct('NodeNumber',i,'NodeDistance',sqrt((node(i).Loc(1)-  node(j).Loc(1))^2+(node(i).Loc(2)-node(j).Loc(2))^2));
     end
   end
 for i = 1:maxn,
 for j = 1:maxn,
    nodedistance(i,j)=rss(i,j).NodeDistance;
 end
 end
   for i = 1:maxn,
   for j = 1:maxn,
       if  (node(i).nEnergy > 0) &&  (node (j).nEnergy > 0) && (0 < nodedistance(i,j) && nodedistance(i,j) <= 30)

       if (node(i).nEnergy < node (j).nEnergy) %|| ( (node(i).nEnergy == node (j).nEnergy )&& (0 < nodedistance(i,j) && nodedistance(i,j)) < 30) %|| (0 < nodedistance(i,j) && nodedistance(i,j) <= 30)

      q(i,j) = 1;

      elseif node(i).nEnergy == node (j).nEnergy && 0 < nodedistance(i,j) && nodedistance(i,j) < 30

       q(i,j) = 1;

      else if 0 < nodedistance(i,j) && nodedistance(i,j) <= 30

        q(i,j) = 1;

      else

        q(i,j) = 0;

      end
      end
      end
      end
      end
      end


        for i = 1:maxn,
          for j = 1:maxn,
              if q(i,j) == 1
                 q(j,i) = 1;
            end 
         end
       end

     colordef white,
     figure(1);
      axis equal
     for i = 1:maxn,
        hold on 
        box on;
        plot(nodeloc(i, 1), nodeloc(i, 2), 'k.', 'MarkerSize', 5);
        lscatter(nodeloc(i, 1),nodeloc(i, 2),i);
       grid on;
     end
       gplot(q,nodeloc,'r-');
      c = q;
      b = 0; zeros(maxn);
      check = 1;
      while (check)
        for m = 2:30
       p = size(b)
       b = zeros(maxn,maxn);
            for i = 1:maxn,
            for j = 1:maxn,
        if i ~= j
        if c(i,j) == 0
        for k = 1:maxn,
       if c(i,k) >0 && q(k,j) >0
       b(i,j) = m;
    break

     else b(i,j) = 0;
     end
     end
     end
     end
     end
     end
        f = size(b)
        c = c + b;
     if b ==0 
          check = 0;
       else b = 0;% while loop here the condition.
     m = m + 1; 
     end
     end
       k = 0;
         for i = 1:maxn,
         for j = 1:maxn,
          k = k + c(i,j);
        end
        end
           average_hop = k/(maxn*(maxn-1));

         o = 0;
         for i = 1:maxn,
         for j = 1:maxn,
         if c(i,j) ~= 0
         o = o + 1;
        end
        end
        end
           c(~c) = nan;
        r=max(max(c));
        t=min(min(c));
      clear
      end 

     formatSpec1 = 'The number of hops from node %d to node %d is %d \n';
      formatSpec2 = 'The average number of hops is %.4f, the maximum hop-count is %d, the minimum hop-count is %d \n';
    formatSpec3 = 'The number of created paths is %d \n';
      fileID = fopen('Paths11.txt','w');
      fprintf(fileID,formatSpec1,i,j,c(i,j));
       fprintf(fileID,formatSpec2,average_hop,r,t);
       fprintf(fileID,formatSpec3,o);

      clear;
      X = X+average_hop;
         Y = Y+r;
      z = Z+t;
        W = W+o; 
         end;

        formatSpec1 = 'The number of hops from node %d to node %d is %d \n';
        formatSpec2 = 'The average number of hops is %.4f, the average maximum hop-count is %.2f, the minimum hop-count is %d \n';
        formatSpec3 = 'The average number of created paths is %.2f \n';
        fileID = fopen('Energy-50-AODV.txt','w');
        fprintf(fileID,formatSpec1,i,j,c(i,j));
        fprintf(fileID,formatSpec2,X/a,Y/a,t);
        fprintf(fileID,formatSpec3,W/a);

        clear;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a get-your-homework-done-for-free site; you'll have to do most of the work yourself. Here are my tips:

- Don't leave your assignments to the last minute.
- Study the MATLAB code of other people working in your field, and refer to the MATLAB help files (hit F1) when you get stuck. Here's a fruitful search query to point you in the right direction: `wsn OR "sensor network" clustering matlab code site:edu`